# Bootstrap Carousel responsive to window size multiple items on one slide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to create a bootstrap carousel in which when viewed in full window size will display and slide multiple items in one go. When the window is re-sized the number of items display will change as well. The number of items to slide depends on the number of items displayed.

Inspired by the carousel/slider in this template: [sample template](https://design.x-cart.com/demo/templates/45-intimates/)

So far, I have this code that displays and slides multiple items (5) in one go. This was possible with the usage of CSS @media. However, when I resize the window the numbers of items displayed changes but still slides 5 items (default number of item active).

```
<?php

function getNew(){
   $results = array();
   
for($z=0; $z<10;$z++) {
   //.... content
}

//js scripts
echo '<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';

//carousel
echo'<div class="container">'; //carousel main container
echo '<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">'; //Carousel slide
echo '<div class="carousel-inner id="carouselCont">'; //carousel-inner

$numb = 1;
$flag = 1;

if(isset($results) && $results >0) {
    
       // listing of newest entry
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($results);$i++){
        
        $rs = $results[$i];

        if ($rs){

            if ($numb == 1 ){
            if ($flag == 1){
                echo '<div class = "item active">';
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class = "item">';
            }
            
            $link = './image/999999999999'.$i.".jpg";
            
            echo '<div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">';
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><div >';
            //.... content                
            echo '</div></a>'; //end of div
        
        }
        elseif ($numb == 5){
        
            $link = './image/999999999999'.$i.".jpg";
            
            echo '<div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">';
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><div>';
            //.... content
              
            echo '</div></a>'; //end of div
            
            $numb = 0;
            echo '</div>'; //end of item every 5 slides
        }
        
        else{
            $link = './image/999999999999'.$i.".jpg";
            
            echo '<div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">';
            
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><div>';
            //..... content
            echo '</div></a>'; //end of div
        }
        
        $numb++;
        $flag++;
       }
       
       echo '</div>'; //end of item
   }
}

echo '</div>'; //end of carousel-inner

echo '</div>'; //end of <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

//carousel-control (left and right)
echo '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>';
echo '<a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span></a>';

echo '</div>'; // end of <div id="container">

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
//stop autoplay
$("#Carousel").carousel({
    interval: false
    })
    
    activeOnResize();       
});
</script>';
    
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    activeOnResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", activeOnResize);

    function activeOnResize(){
        //window width
        var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();

        $(".carousel-inner .item").removeClass("active");
        
        //5 SLIDES
        if (windowWidth > 1200){
            
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(4)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(5)").addClass("active");
            
        }
        //4 SLIDES
        elseif ((windowWidth < 1200) && (windowWidth >= 991)){
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(4)").addClass("active");
        }
        //3 SLIDES
        elseif ((windowWidth < 990) && (windowWidth >= 750)){
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3)").addClass("active");
        }   
                
        else{
            $(".carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
        }         
    }
</script>';
}
?>
```

I'm using the script above that removes the existing item active classes and detects the window size that decides how many items to change its class to an active one. However, it doesn't respond and displays blank without the help of customized CSS @media. I'm afraid it doesn't go inside the if-else condition for the window size and change the classes done above.

Is it possible to create a responsive bootstrap carousel that slides multiple items in one go with the help of jQuery or javascript? I'm quite new to jQuery and javascript. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.